# Why the distance between two keys is called "semitone"

Tags: theory, intervals

Why is the distance between two closest keys called semitone? I guess there some historical reasons for that. If I was to construct the piano/music nomenclature from scratch I would call the smallest distance between two keys a "unit" and not a "semiunit".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why wasn't the actual "semitone" taken as the unit and therefore called "a tone"?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/62443/why-wasnt-the-actual-semitone-taken-as-the-unit-and-therefore-called-a-tone)

Answer (score 2):

Western music theory evolved from trying to explain and describe tonal music. Tonal music uses the diatonic scale as its main musical device. In the diatonic scale, there are seven notes: do, re, mi, fa, sol, la, si and do again. The viewpoint that was initially used to describe this scale sees the large distances between do-re, re-mi, fa-sol, sol-la and la-si (the majority of distances) as the most important and called these 'tones', while the distances mi-fa, and si-do are smaller and therefore called 'semi-tones'.

It's when Western music evolved to incorporate more and more keys, and with the invention of the equal temperament, that the notes between those of the diatonic scale (do#, re#, fa#, sol#, la#) became more and more important. From a 20th and 21st century viewpoint all the 12 notes of the chromatic scale seem more or less 'equal', and the diatonic scale is seen as a subset of this chromatic scale. From this viewpoint a semi-tone looks like the fundamental 'unit', but historically it wasn't.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work. You have 6 tones in an octave (12 semitones): C D E Gb Ab Bb C.

Comment: @yo' - the point is, that there are seven *steps* in the diatonic scale, and five of these seven steps are what we call "whole tones".  The whole tone scale has practically no musical currency.

Comment: I would say that increasing importance of the chromatic notes drove the adoption of equal temperament rather than the other way around.

Comment: @phoogYes, I think you are right, altough it also went the other way: because of the invention of equal temperament it was possible to explore an increased chromaticism.